# Convex Polyhedra Scissors Congruence Problem

Tags: discrete-geometry, polyhedra, scissors-congruence

I am currently writing a geometry paper "Rectifications of Convex Polyhedra" and I am confused to have discovered what appears to be a remarkable discrete geometric fact:

**Conjecture: Let $P$ be a convex polyhedron. Then $P \cong P^{\circ} \sqcup R_{1}[P]$.**

The relation $\cong$ is to denote scissors congruence, the dual polyhedron is $P^{\circ}$, and $R_{1}[P]$ is the first rectification of $P$, defined as
$$R_{1}[P] = \text{conv} \left\{\frac{x_{i} + x_{j}}{2} \; | \; (i,j) \in E(P) \right\}.$$

I have been drawing many examples of when this happens to work out (cube decomposing into a rectified cube (cuboctahedron) and eight pieces (orthoschemes) which rearrange to be an octahedron; octahedron decomposing into a rectified octahedron (cuboctahedron) and six pieces which rearrange to be a cube; tetrahedron decomposing into a rectified tetrahedron (octahedron) and four pieces which rearrange to be a tetrahedron. I've also tried various examples of prisms and bipyramids which all appear to work, I believe if a counterexample exists it will be non-centrally symmetric and I am working on a proof in the case of centrally symmetric convex polyhedra.

I am interested in classifying which convex polyhedra this holds for if there is a counterexample to the conjecture.

Comment: How does the volume work out? Are you scaling the RHS pieces?

Comment: As @DouglasZare says, you need to specify how the polyhedra are scaled. If you only had one polyhedron on the RHS, the scaling would be unique to get the volumes to be the same; but as it stands, you haven't specified the relative scaling between $P^\circ$ and $R_1[P]$.

Comment: I think that scaling is important but for any unit tetrahedron there is not a scissors decomposition into  a smaller regular tetrahedron and a regular octahedron see my revised answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the conjecture is true then the for the unit tetrahedron it will have a unit tetrahedron decomposible into a smaller regular tetrahedron and a regular octahedron. The regular octahedron of side $a$ will have Dehn invariant equal to $-2$ times the Dehn invariant of the tetrahedron side $a$. Hence its Dehn invariant will be -$2a$ times the Dehn invariant of the unit tetrahedron. the tetrahedron will have side $b$ less than one and its Dehn invariant will be $b$ times the Dehn invariant of the tetrahedron of side $1$. So one one side of the equation we will have the Dehn invariant of the unit tetrahedron and on the other side $b-2a$ times the Dehn invariant of the unit tetrahedron where $b$ is less than one and $a$ is positive and we cannot have equality.

Comment: I think you need to pay attention to the relative size of the pieces, as indicated in Doug Zare's comment.

Comment: The only thing that matters in three dimensions is the dehn invariant.

Comment: Thank you for your counterexample. Do you think there is any class of polyhedra for which the conjecture holds? Maybe simple/simplicial polyhedra, or self-dual polyhedra.

Comment: I think the simple polyhedra include the dodecahedron and in that case the same argument gives a contradiction.

Comment: The icosahedron is simplicial so that is a counterexample.

Comment: The tetrahedron is self dual the conjecture would imply it could be decomposed into a octahedron and a tetrahedron but since the octahedron has dehn invariant equal to negative two times the dehn invariant of the tetrahedron that would imply the dehn invariant of the tetrahedron equals its negative and hence equals zero which is false.

Comment: More pecisely, in three dimensions, all that matters is the volume and the Dehn invariant. Both of these change when the polyhedron is changed, but in different ways. (The Dehn invariant is the sum of (length) tensor (dihedral angle) over the edges of the polyhedron; the length changes). So I don't see why an arbitrary combination of an icosahedron, an icosidodecahedron, and a dodecahedron (with differing edge lengths) should be decomposable to a cube. Conway-Radin-Sadun prove the case where all of them have unit edge length.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I think I have a counterexample regardless of scaling. I have redone the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insightful discussion, I see that this phenomenon only appears to be holding in very specific cases up to scaling. I was interested in it because I have been attempting to calculate explicit formulas for the volume of duals in order to prove the Mahler conjecture for certain classes of convex polytopes.

Comment: What do you mean by "sign" and "absolute value" of the Dehn invariant? The way I think about the Dehn invariant, it lives in $\mathbb{R} \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} (\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z})$, which is an infinite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ with no natural norm or ordering.

Comment: I have redone the proof with everything in terms of the dehn value of the unit tetrahedron. You are right the dehn value is a tensor product without norm or ordering.

Comment: @Dylan Thurston: There are times when it seems intuitive to project from the natural domain to $\mathbb{R}$, such as in the oft-proved result (of Debrunner) that if a polyhedron tiles $\mathbb{R}^3$, its Dehn invariant is $0$. If you think of the Dehn invariant living in $\mathbb R$, then it is natural to use the square-cube ratio to say that the projected Dehn invariant must be arbitrarily small, hence $0$.